# How to parse following xml file using JAXB or any other parser

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have following xml file and I want to convert it into Java object using JXAB. Can some suggest which parser will do the job efficiently if there any better than JAXB?

Right now I only needs some of fields from the file but in future I am sure I will need most of them, So I am looking for solution that will convert all fields into object attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
        <plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadContent</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>PayloadCertificateFileName</key>
                    <string>pkiclient.exe.cer</string>
                    <key>PayloadContent</key>
                    <data>
                    MIIDWzCCAkOgAwIBAgIIbbXoNrXgWrUwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
                    OzEVMBMGA1UEAwwMTWFuYWdlbWVudENBMRUwEwYDVQQKDAxFSkJD
                    QSBTYW1wbGUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlNFMB4XDTE1MDYwOTExMTQzN1oX
                    DTI1MDYwNjExMTQzN1owOzEVMBMGA1UEAwwMTWFuYWdlbWVudENB
                    MRUwEwYDVQQKDAxFSkJDQSBTYW1wbGUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlNFMIIB
                    IjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA41riRAQHXODW
                    w8ihGSmf/OYByA4z0fQHLdTPzcu3fg0wvY72b74Hwo4DHEtna8I+
                    ZQ0y16vx1y/RBQR7KWJR5NkKK+mdtxdlp4Ef7IrPBAg4donT8h7I
                    S7/AMA8KEzzCza0nhK+lWejtLaWSnjVZ60nz/6R/kLn2chWOHFga
                    9JOdB7dPovv27eBE5+08xmRfzc5bguqVslcDcW6xLfkR3ChhXn7L
                    C2V9DR+y3J+Tjo/iWkyJH3XAe+jHh8gpGvMroolm7axKSDEKl0PD
                    LR2AYxrMDYpR70m6aMKs/q2dlbykCzDwLhXGxDmjcxyZU/cqyXMZ
                    5BEHI+7hSFGyXlv6tQIDAQABo2MwYTAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUtUUcq/GH
                    iBHrkanRtz4Y6EnWSocwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAfBgNVHSME
                    GDAWgBS1RRyr8YeIEeuRqdG3PhjoSdZKhzAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMC
                    AYYwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAMZMwmp5+YemWxnvWI4dw9Hz
                    rnzuI4It2HLDnCTE7GDrE8TI3lb+ZNxuuK7NKr0IgIQsuZzEiRCb
                    oq2OWnGXLvvqq5F0EybdiYCLU1E1OjqqQlOW9wWHB35PZUb6tQi2
                    hCoafFy9CUDLcRS95I0Og7rbszFZAcQrKpyF+qSRAFcrD6O1JCSk
                    ad+giQBsfD/erRFPd7mVHVjm5O+T8Sz8LL5MgI7decRhjfADVW16
                    ZWdajhgBnmeW+KTnOJfEMjqMmU6JeSl26rbSqcWR28Or2smXkRkX
                    LUA8j/B3FbUTQ+MOSJSj+rl54f0iAs4Tzey7Pgh7D2rtgrjM4M3M
                    0iky3FM=
                    </data>
                    <key>PayloadDescription</key>
                    <string>Configures certificate settings.</string>
                    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
                    <string>ManagementCA</string>
                    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
                    <string>com.apple.security.root.43EA4618-C9DF-439E-A346-C4CCDD73FAA6</string>
                    <key>PayloadType</key>
                    <string>com.apple.security.root</string>
                    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
                    <string>43EA4618-C9DF-439E-A346-C4CCDD73FAA6</string>
                    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
                    <integer>1</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>PayloadContent</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>CAFingerprint</key>
                        <data>
                        </data>
                        <key>Challenge</key>
                        <string>Password1</string>
                        <key>Key Type</key>
                        <string>RSA</string>
                        <key>Keysize</key>
                        <integer>2048</integer>
                        <key>Subject</key>
                        <array>
                            <array>
                                <array>
                                    <string>CN</string>
                                    <string>150615987102</string>
                                </array>
                            </array>
                        </array>
                        <key>URL</key>
                        <string>http://172.20.16.158:8080/ejbca/publicweb/apply/scep/testSCEP/pkiclient.exe</string>
                    </dict>
                    <key>PayloadDescription</key>
                    <string>Configures SCEP settings</string>
                    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
                    <string>SCEP</string>
                    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
                    <string>com.apple.security.scep.FC189619-2F84-4E39-AE66-5E037D8A8A84</string>
                    <key>PayloadType</key>
                    <string>com.apple.security.scep</string>
                    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
                    <string>FC189619-2F84-4E39-AE66-5E037D8A8A84</string>
                    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
                    <real>1</real>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>EJBTest</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>bhaidass-macbook-pro.local.736DF58F-4375-420A-B9D6-7950684E0B3A</string>
            <key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
            <false/>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>Configuration</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>A8F41F59-643C-44B5-9447-8AB88D6FCA49</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        </plist>
```

Comment: JAXB can unmarshal a  `<dict>` element as a list of key/string/data/real/integer elements.  If you want to have it convenient for the application programmer accessing this data, you might build a conversion of the list to a `Map<String,Object>` - Object because you have three different data types in the value domain. Writing an adapter has been explained elsewhere and can be found using a search engine, or looking back a few jaxb posts on SO. - The treble nested `<array>` element probably requires another adapter - it is unclear what its Java representation should be.

Comment: Thanks laune, It will be very helpful if you provide some links for adapter based parsing for complex xml using JAXB. For your question, There is no specific java representation I just need java object that will give me values from this xml file.